# Python fails to parse objects list from valid yaml

Tags: python, yaml

I have yaml config:

```
base: /tmp
tasks: 
  - 
    drop: true
    dump_src: "some string here"
    dump_ts: "some string here"
    region: ME
  - 
    dump_src: "some string here"
    dump_ts: "some string here"
    region: RU
```

It passes http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/ and http://www.yamllint.com/ validation

But when I try:

```
import yaml

if __name__ == "__main__":
    stream = open(sys.argv[0], 'r')
    docs = yaml.load_all(stream)
    for doc in docs:
        print doc
```

I've got an error:

```
yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here
  in "/opt/projects/nextgis/gazetteer-update/gup-web.py", line 7, column 40
```

Answer (score 1):

Have found my mistake:

```
stream = open(sys.argv[0], 'r')
```

`sys.argv[0]` is python script itself, so I've tried to parse a script, not a yaml config.

Correct arg value is under index 1:

```
stream = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
```